# HTML div id background image not showing when its identical to another id?

Tags: html, css, image, background

This is the css style sheet for my page its driving me mad image will show for navi id
but not main id why? i used a different image at first it wouldnt work so i changed it to the same image and still nothing shows the page works not the background image, is it because its a floating div or something? or because its a div inside a div?

```
body{
        background-color: gray; /* dont need to call id*/
        font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, arial;  /* set the font for the whole body,                                          use back up fonts too*/
    }

    a{ /*In the same way we targeted the body tag we can target the a tag*/
        text-decoration: none; /* links not underlined*/
            color: red; /* links are coloured red*/
    }

    #container{
        background-color:white;
        width: 800px;
        margin-left: auto; /*to center there container*/
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    h1{ /* using commas i could set it for h1,h2,h3*/
        margin:0; /* gets rid of margin*/
    }

    #header {
        background-color: blue; /* background of div id set to blue */
        color: red; /* text set to red*/
        text-align: center; /* aligns text in the header to middle of page*/
        padding: 0x;
    }

    /* #content{ padding-left:10px and all seperate directions or can use 
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px
        1st is top 2nd is right 3rd is bottom and 4th is the left and since want 
        all the same we can shorten even more and just put 10px*/

    #content {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #navi{
        width:180px;
        height:500px;
        float: left; /*as divs always start a new line to stop this we use float*/
        background-image:url("navi.png");

    #navi ul{
        list-style-type: none; /* gets rid of the bullet points after targeting ul*/
        padding: 0; /*gets rid of padding */
    }

    /*.selected*/ /*#for id . for class*/
    #navi .selected{ /* if we wanted to be more specific if there was selected class elsewhere
                        also if we wanted to select all selected class and navi
                        its #navi, .selected */
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #main{
        width: 600px;
        height:500px;
        float: right; 
        background-image:url("navi.png");
    }


    #footer{
        clear: both; /* this is to clear of all floating elements or will not appear
                         below, clearing both lets the div element get past all 
                         the floating div elements*/    
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #999999;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

The html file im using is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Chill </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
                <div id="header">
             <img src="img.jpg" width="800" height="200" alt="logo" /> <!-- setting 
                                                                            image as header -->
                </div> 

            <div id="content">
                <div id="navi">
                    <h3> Navigation</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li> <!-- creating a css class   
                                                                called selected as this is
                                                                 the page we are on -->
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                </div>

                <div id="main">
                    <h2> Home page</h2>
                    <p>CompSci Vs. CompEngineering. </p>    
                    <p>Help me decide, please! </p>
                    <p>Any suggestions on accessible texts on algorithms?</p>
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div id="footer">
            Footer Copyright &copy; Aza
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually you are using #main meaning it is targetting an id not a class

Comment: Your title suggests 2 nodes with the same ID, which is a no-no, and could well be your problem.

Comment: I'd recommend validating your CSS before anything else, your `#navi` styles do not have a closing brace: `}`

Comment: provide your html code, because we need to see how is estructurated..and your css check your brackets :-D

Comment: thanks where can i validate my css? so frustrated i was reading things like "Divs which are containers consider themselves to have zero height, and consequently show no color. To fool them you must put a overflow:hidden" and/or that as it was a floating element it isnt a background image so you have define it as a block element "display:block;" when really all it came down to was a simple syntax error! Is there any sense in the comments made I just mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

## navi{...

navi has no closing bracket in the css above.

Can you provide a piece of the html you are using?

Comment: The brace did the job!! I love you